# Launching and executing python script from web browser / UI

Tags: python

Requirement is to create an UI for business user i.e. non-technical who wants to select python scripts and execute from web interface with a click of button. Purpose is to not reveal the source code to business user.

I did made an attempt to host Jupyter on an EC2 instance and sharing the URL with folks internally within organization but that opens up source code in front of business person.Need of the hour is a business user launches a URL where there will be a list of python scripts and one can be selected and executed.

Comment: where should the script be executed? on the clients machine? on a server?

Comment: @Sadap it should happen on server . Requirement is to develop number of python scripts which can be made available on a UI and user can launch and see the output on that UI

Comment: Sounds like you want to build some web application. Django or Flask are two out of many options for Python web frameworks.

Comment: @Feodoran - Not exactly a web app but a better way to expose repository full of python scripts to non-technical users who can come to this URL and launch , see the output and go from there

Comment: How is that not a web application?

Comment: @Feodoran Yes, you are right taxonomy wise it is a web-app but purpose is like IDE of non-technical user who can launch and execute with click of button without seeing the actual source code

Comment: It should not be a problem to build a web app like this. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I agree with @Feodoran. A web application with django or flask will be the best solution

Comment: @Feodoran - It helps additionally I am looking more information on architecture like serverless , soa , etc.,